# Ember.js: how to catch all JS errors thrown by a component

Tags: ember.js

using ember v3.5, is there a way to catch all JS errors thrown by a component (ex errors thrown in computed fields without having to use try-catch in all computed fields)?
Thank you!

Comment: I don't think this is possible. But we might be able to provide an alternative solution, if you elaborate a little bit on your use case. What are you trying to achieve by catching all the errors?

Comment: Ok, thank you @jelhan. I'll use an alternate solution. Thanks for the response.